# The problem about springcloudproject resource?

Tags: spring-boot

springcloud project have porblem?

[THYMELEAF][http-nio-6969-exec-2] Exception processing template "/ticketPage/ticketList": An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/ticketPage/ticketList.html]")?

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/ticketPage/ticketList.html]")

Comment: //进入ticketList页面，已购列表
    @RequestMapping("/ticketList")
    public String ticketList(HttpServletRequest request,
                             @RequestParam(defaultValue = "1") Integer currentPage,
                             @RequestParam(defaultValue = "10") Integer pageSize) {
        System.out.println("\n进入ticketList页面");
        request.setAttribute("ticketList", ticketFeignService.getAll(currentPage, pageSize));
        request.setAttribute("pages", new Pages(currentPage, pageSize, (int) ticketFeignService.getCount()));
        return "/ticketPage/ticketList";
}

Comment: Don't add additional information as comments as that is totally unreadable. This appears nothing to do with SPring Cloud but with a wrong template. Please add your configuration, code, template to the quiestion and please use proper code tags for formatting! See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask